# Defining variable start position with ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I would like to have a variable start point for my initial conditions in `ParametricNDSolve`. I was hoping ideally this would look like the following (with a random DE used for the example).

```
soln = ParametricNDSolve[{v''[x] == 10, v'[a] == 1, v[a] == 1}, 
  v, {x, a, 10}, {a}]

vsoln = v /. soln


vsoln[1]
```

However, this gives the following error:

[image]

My expectation is that this is caused by Mathematica not evaluating the given value of `a` first and so the initial values for the variable are not defined in a way that it can access. Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated. I'm not nessasarily tied to using `ParametricNDSolve` but I would like to avoid having to do a change of variable to set `v[a]` $\to$ `v*[0]`, where `v*` is some shifted function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Original Solution

One possible solution is to change `ParametricNDSolve` to `NDSolve` but hold the evaluation of the equation. Then later when you're ready and know the desired value of `a` make the appropriate substitution for `a` and release the evaluation:

```
soln = Hold[
  NDSolve[{v''[x] == 10, v'[a] == 1, v[a] == 1}, v, {x, a, 10}]]

vsoln[aa_] :=  v /. First[ReleaseHold[ReplaceAll[soln,  a -> aa]]]

vsoln[1]

Plot[vsoln[1][t], {t, 1., 10.}]
```

[image]
[image]

### A Second Method

A very similar alternative method that I think is more intuitive is to instead of holding include a condition to not evaluate unless a numerical value is given:

```
soln[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{v''[x] == 10, v'[a] == 1, v[a] == 1}, v, {x, a, 10}]


vsoln[a_] := v /. First[soln[a]]

vsoln[1]
Plot[vsoln[1][t], {t, 1, 10}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Now, I'm actually quite surprised that this isn't the default behavior of `ParametricNDSolve`. If anyone has more knowledge is there an intuitive reason it doesn't behave in the above manner?

Comment: That `ParametricNDSolve(Value)` is unable to do this looks [reportable](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback) to me; I see no obvious reason why it should fail.

Comment: @J.M. thanks! I'll fill out that document!

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can use [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
eqns = {v''[x] == 10, v'[a] == 1, v[a] == 1};

soln = DSolve[eqns, v, x][[1]]

(* {v -> Function[{x}, 1 - a + 5 a^2 + x - 10 a x + 5 x^2]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqns /. soln

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Plotting,

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[v[x] /. soln], {x, 0, 10}, {a, 0, 5},
 ColorFunction ->
  Function[{x, a, v}, ColorData[97][If[x >= a, 2, 1]]],
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, a, v})]
```

[image]

Comment: I was assuming the OP just posted a toy example, but really had a problem with a more complicated RHS.